# The term 'NODE_ENV=development' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: node.js, npm, nodeenv

I want to set some env variable in my node app but when I run this command `NODE_ENV=development x=23 nodemon.cmd server.js`[image] then it gives me that error NODE_ENV=development' is not recognized, I found some solution where it said that I have to run a
npm package `npm install -g win-node-env` then it will work, but in my case, I got the same error. I am a windows user, any solution how to fix this.

Comment: This issue is that isn't how you set environmental variables within the PowerShell CLI. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may or may not relevant to your question, but as far as I know, windows powershell syntax does not assign variable that way.

to assign variable in windows, you can subtitute `NODE_ENV=development` with `$NODE_ENV:development`

As a workaround, and if you want to run it on any OS, use `cross-env` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

```sh
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

Now, it can run command such as:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I install the cross-env package and and run `cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js` but it showes that it is not recognized but using Command Prompt solve my problem.

Comment: @MohammadAliShuvo please mark the answer if it's solves your problem